# GXT - link two components height

Tags: gwt, gxt

I want to have a panel, with two columns.

The first column will contain a list of beans, and the right one a form panel for editing those beans. What I want to do, is that list height is the same as height of the form panel on the right. My list of beans will be larger and larger over time, so it's height will probably exceed form height. When that happens, there should be a scrollbar showed for the list. I also don't want to set explicit size for list and my form panel (it should be flexible because some time I will add or remove some form fields).
I'm basically new to GXT. I'm looking forward for some proposals.

Cheers,
jjczopek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the CSS style overflow-y: auto; with max-hight on the Panel (div?) on which you need a scroll bar. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set Fill or Fit Layout.